# Compare two quadratic function

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

if we know

$ x^T S_1 x > y^TS_2y $ ,

$x$ and $y$ are vectors, $S_1$ and $ S_2$ are semi-positive definite matrices

is the following conclusion true?

$ x^T S_1x > x^TS_2x $

Comment: Not in general. Take $y=0$ for instance.

Comment: suppose y and x are not equal to zero

Comment: Are you talking about all real vectors $x$ and $y$?

Comment: yes dear! I need it to prove some theorem

Comment: @ehsanshokri If that's the case then put $y=x$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Ok, not zero then, still not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. Take $y=0$ for instance.

For non zero vectors, fix $S_1,S_2$ such that the second condition does not hold. Then the coordinates of $y$ can be as small as you want, such that the first condition holds.

Maybe if you give more information about the vectors or the matrices, something can be concluded.